# How to run a python script with a python script in Linux

Tags: python, linux

I am running in Linux and I need to open another python script with a python script and in windows it was as easy as

```
import os
os.startfile(dir)
```

but now im in Linux it gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dev/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/vpn.py", line 1, in <module>
    os.startfile('main.py')
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'startfile'
```

what do I use to run files in Linux?

I'm using `zorin os 16.1 (Ubuntu)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I prefer to use `os.system('python main.py')`, since it is the same as just running the command `python main.py` from your command line

Comment: I think I can make this work, thanks.